# Relationship between Union/Intersection types and (co)monads

Tags: typescript, haskell, types, monads

While exploring typescript I noticed that the inference rules for union and intersection types (with one argument instantiated) are distinctly monad- and comonad- like, respectively. With some suggestive naming, we have

```
type Union X = X | B
join: Union (Union X) == Union X
pure: X <: (Union X)

type Intersect X = X & B
dup: Intersect X == Intersect (Intersect X) 
extract: Intersect X <: X
```

These look like strictified versions of (co)monads, and satisfy analogues of the (co)monad laws, except they aren't endofunctors (`bind` is the closest we can get to `map` and afaict has to be implemented separately).

Is this just a cute coincidence or is there something deeper going on?

Comment: This is really cool! What do you mean by "strictified"?

Comment: Aren't these indeed endofunctors on the category of types with subtyping arrows (opposed to function arrows)?

Comment: @Quelklef I mean that when previously there was a morphism between 2 types, there is now an equality

Comment: @ChristophSachse Note that Leibniz equality is in fact a morphism. In particular, it's the identity morphism. See, https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/papers/leibniz/leibniz.pdf.

Comment: @HTNW Ah I think you're right! since the subtyping arrow category is skeletal that explains why it became an equality

Comment: `Intersect` is not a comonad. It's not even a functor.

Comment: `Union` is a monad, but only for certain types of `B` such as `string`. For example, `Union` is not even a functor when `B` is non-trivial such as `{ foo: string }`. You're better off sticking to `Either` instead of `Union` and tuples instead of `Intersect`.

Comment: @AaditMShah If you read the question you'll see that I specifically mentioned that. I think HTNW is right that they are functors in the subtyping category, where we can write the defintion `map (f : X <: Y) (x) = x as Y`

Comment: Sure, in a category with types as objects and subtype relations as morphisms, `Union` is a monad and `Intersect` is a comonad. However, there's nothing profound going on here. Both `Union` and `Intersect` are idempotent. Hence, `Union X` is trivially equal to `Union (Union X)` and `Union (Union (Union X))`. Same for `Intersect`. And, `X <: Union X` and `Intersect X <: X` just follow from the definitions of unions and intersections.

Comment: @ChristophSachse If I did not even understand a question, which books should I read to understand it ?

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine Most resources on statically-typed functional programming will do, I liked Bartosz Milewski's talks or books (Category theory for programmers/Dao of Functional Programming)

Comment: @ChristophSachse I have read 50% of his book  Category Theory. Was not able to finish his book because of lack of understanding